# Unreachable code and fail to read all the input letter

Tags: c

I am writing a short program in c language which basically asks users to enter a secret key will consist of the five characters a,b,c,d,r listed in some order, each appearing exactly once, with no spaces. And then the program asks the user to enter 7 letters which also consist of the five characters a,b,c,d,r in some order.
So there is a natural order a,b,c,d,r. So each letter entered in the "7 letters", will be changed to the encrypted one as the letter in the natural order will be changed to the letter in the corresponding place in the secret key. For example, if the secret key is r,b,c,d,a and the 7 letters are a,b,b,a,c,c,r. The encrypted one will be r,b,b,r,c,c,a. And the encrypted one will be printed out. If the user enters more than 7 letters, the program will only read the first 7 letters and if the user enters letters other than a,b,c,d,r in the 7 letters, the program will report an error and terminate.

So now I wrote the program and tested it. However, while I have spent 3 hours debugging it, it still said there are some unreachable codes and the scanf() seems cannot capture all the 7 letters the user enter. Could anyone help me check my codes? Thanks a lot.

```
int main() {
char natural[5]={'a','b','c','d','r'};
char key[5];
char word[7];
printf("     Enter key: ");
scanf("%1c%1c%1c%1c%1c",&key[0],&key[1],&key[2],&key[3],&key[4]);
printf("    Enter word: ");
int LetterNum;
LetterNum=scanf("%1c%1c%1c%1c%1c%1c%1c",&word[0],&word[1],&word[2],&word[3],
&word[4],&word[5],&word[6]);
for(int i=0;i<LetterNum;i++){
if(word[i]!='a'||word[i]!='b'||word[i]!='c'||word[i]!='d'||word[i]!='r'){
    printf("You did not speak in ABRACADABRA to me!\n");
    return 0;
    }
}

 printf("Encrypted word: ");
 char encrypted[LetterNum]; 
for(int i=0;i<LetterNum;i++){
for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
    if(word[i]==natural[x])
            encrypted[i]=key[x];
    }
}
     for(i=0;i<LetterNum;i++){
   printf("%c",encrypted[i]);
  }
   printf("\n");


}
```

Thank you very much! I am new to C language, so probably there are some silly mistakes I did not realize...

Comment: Use `char word[8];` and  `scanf("%8s", word)` please.

Comment: Your ORs should be ANDs (`||` --> `&&`)

Comment: You need to consume newlines at the first input.

Comment: Your condition `word[i]!='a'||word[i]!='b'|| ...` will always be true, since it has to be unequal to at least *one* of those characters.  The compiler might be recognizing this, and eliminating the test altogether, which results in an unconditional `return`.  To fix it, change `||` to `&&`.  That way you will execute the `if` body if `word[i]` isn't *any* of those characters.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi sorry I cannot use string at this moment since I can only include <studio.h>. And could I know why word[8] since I think 7 slots for the first 7 letters.

Comment: @DannyC When dealing with strings, you always need to allow one character for the terminating null byte (assuming you want a null-terminated string).  If you never treat it as a string, but only as an array of individual characters, then you could skip the extra byte, but you have to be very careful if you do that.

Comment: @DannyC `scanf("%8s", word)`  is a mistake of `scanf("%7s", word)`. Also, since this does not force 7-character input, there is not much profit because it is necessary to check the number of input characters separately. Also, you can simply write `scanf("%1c%1c%1c%1c%1c",&key[0],&key[1],&key[2],&key[3],&key[4]);` like `scanf("%5c", key);` or (`scanf("%5c%*c", key);` This will consume the following newline.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unreacability is that the compiler has analyzed that the `if` statement with the ORs will always be true and so will execute the return and so the rest is unreachable.

```
if(word[i]!='a'||word[i]!='b'||word[i]!='c'||word[i]!='d'||word[i]!='r'){ // is always true

if(word[i]!='a'&&word[i]!='b'&&word[i]!='c'&&word[i]!='d'&&word[i]!='r'){  // is correct
```

(would you have used a debugger to step through the program, you have found this yourself)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I was so silly and made such mistakes lol. But could I know why the scanf() cannot capture the 7 letters? As I have tried to write printf(“%c”,word[0]) which just follows the scanf() statement and it seems to print nothing I entered but a new line..